# Getting friends' ids, but not names, from FB.api?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook

I've got some javascript code that calls out to Facebook via FB.api and asks for the current user's friends.  It's the usual thing --

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function (response) { ... });
```

It's successfully bringing back an object containing the user's friends' ID numbers, but not their names.  I'm now very confused -- according to all the documentation I've been able to find, the names should be coming back as well.

Any insights here?  Where did the names go? Is there some special permission I need to be requesting from the user?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo and behold, this appears to be an actual bug, as of 1 Dec 11: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/289460071094864 .  It seems to affect test users only.  I'll declare this to be closed, pending whatever FB does about it (and when they get around to it).